# i need a help converting a 3 column list to a 3 column array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have this type of list:

```
List<List<List<int>>> abc = new List<List<List<int>>>();
```

And this type of array:

```
int[][][] ttt;
```

I want `ttt` to get `abc`.  How do I do that?

Thank you.

I tried LINQ using so:

```
LocatedText.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToArray()
```

However, it fits only 2 column lists.

Comment: may we ask WHY you want to do this? lists support indexing and then some, and they use arrays internally. what problem are you hoping to achieve by doing this (there might be a better way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to already have the tools you need.

If this converts one:

```
LocatedText.ToArray()
```

And this converts two:

```
LocatedText.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToArray()
```

Then it seems reasonable that this would probably convert three:

```
LocatedText.Select(l1 => l1.Select(l2 => l2.ToArray()).ToArray()).ToArray()
```

Or, perhaps somewhat more readably:

```
LocatedText.Select(l1 =>
    l1.Select(l2 =>
        l2.ToArray())
    .ToArray())
.ToArray()
```

(Well, *perhaps*.  Readability is in the eye of the beholder.)